# Is there a function in R to pack several individual graphs into a "Network.List"?

Tags: r, igraph, adjacency-matrix, sna, ggraph

Please excuse me in advance if I do not express myself completely correctly. I am still relatively new in this field.

I work with different packages (e.g. igraph, network, networkDynamic, ggraph etc.) and have also tried different solutions.

I have several adjacency matrices (each of these matrices contains a change of the edges or their weights over time), with which I create individual networks with the command `network()`. In order to create a dynamic network from them, I would like to represent these networks as a `network.list`, so that I can insert them into the command `networkDynamic()`.

I came up with this idea via the "Newcomb's Fraternity Networks" network-dataset, which represents a `network.list`. I have tried it with this network-dataset and it works.

```
networkDynamic(network.list = newcomb, create.TEAs = TRUE)
```

The subsequent display via `render.d3movie()` also works.

Is there a possibility to create a `network.list` from several adjacency matrices or their graphs?

I am also open for alternative suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

the `network.list` is just a simple list. create an empty list and store the time-slices of your network in it, like:

```
network_list <- list()
network_list[[1]] <- network_1
network_list[[2]] <- network_2
network_list[[3]] <- network_3
network_list[[4]] <- network_4
network_list[[5]] <- network_5
```

you can then convert it to a `networkDynamic` object through

```
network_dynamic <- networkDynamic(network.list = network_list, create.TEAs = T)
```

Answer (score -1):

In case others also come across this topic:
I found the solution on this website
[Skye Bender-deMoll (04/05/2016): Temporal network tools in statnet: networkDynamic, ndtv and tsna](https://web.archive.org/web/20181116144112/http://statnet.csde.washington.edu:80/workshops/SUNBELT/current/ndtv/ndtv_workshop.html)